# Verify In JSON Object ,does value has special character

Tags: java, json, error-handling

I am looking for solution where if my payload has special character throw error.
For eg
{
"id" :"#123"
}
or
{
"id" : "123"
"name" : #shilpa
}
In both I need to throw 400 bad request.
Any help is really appreciated

Comment: What part are you stuck with? Deserialising the json, checking a string for invalid characters, or sending back responses?

Comment: Also what language is this? You haven't shown any code or specified one

Comment: Here iterating fields I am stuck.I have some set of fields .where some may have special character,some doesnt :(

Comment: And also I am new to Java

Comment: That's fine, but there's very little information in your question. What code do you have? Have you tried anything yet? What frameworks are you using for HTTP requests/responses? Without this, we can't help

Comment: JerseyAPi ,I know how to throw exception,however I need help in comparing values for regex ..Thanks alot Byxor @byxor.Im glad tht you are helping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201932/discussion-between-shilpa-and-byxor).

Answer (score 0):

i'm not a Web Developer but i can suggest what i would do,

first of all convert the object to an array and iterate on it :

```
const arrayJson= Object.keys(jsonInput).map(i => jsonInput[i]);
```

now you have an array.

with this array you can do a for loop and check if unexpected input was given.

for exaple :

```
for( var i = 0; i < arrayJson.length; i++) {
   if(arrayJson[i] === "#"){
    // example
    console.log("Error 400"
}
  // and so on...more condition
}
```

another way is with Regualar Expression.

But put it in a function like:

```
function checkChar(jsonObject){

 for( var i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; i++) {
       if(jsonObject[i] === "#"){
        // example
        console.log("Error 400"
    }
      // and so on...more condition
    }
}
```

and then just call it or use a IIFE !

Sorry if i couldn't write the whole code 100% for you, but i try to help even when its  not my programming language.

Comment: Hi, Object.keys is not available in Java :(